# Design Issue: Reputation Gold Badges Not Visible in Meta

Tags: bug, badges

In Meta, I'm not seeing the Gold Badges display for reputation. Are others seeing the same issue here? They appear fine in the regular forum. Here's what I'm seeing.

[image: Reputation and Badges]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a different set of badges specific to your achievements on meta. Unless you're eligible for a gold badge based on your activities on meta they won't show up here.

Comment: I always felt this was the case but the previous design never displayed them differently. Am I the only one who's noticing this?

Comment: @crmprogdev They've always been different, I'm 100% certain on this as it confused me the very first time I came on meta.

Comment: They didn't display that way for me in recent months. I recognize there are different badges, but I always saw the same count for the last several months when entering Meta. Perhaps it was a "bug" that's been "fixed". I had thought it odd behavior as it wasn't always that way for me.